# How do I monitor all packets flowing to and from a particular device on my home network?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I want to use wireshark to capture packets flowing to and from an ip camera on my home network? Would I somehow route all its traffic through my alfa network adapter? The camera is controlled via mobile app and is wirelessly connected to my router.

I was able to capture some packets sent from the device to a server when the device started up but beyond that nothing.

Sorry if this is basic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most High end Routers and Wi-Fi Access points have the ability to capture traffic, or mirror traffic. If it is Captured, you can download the capture right from the Router/AP, if it is mirror, you can attach a laptop to the Mirror port, and run Wireshark to capture the traffic.

Now, for home devices, your options are limited. One option is the setup Ad hoc Access Point on a Laptop, connect the Camera to this AP, run Wireshark. Same setup, if you can connect it through a LAN cable to Laptop, and then bridge the traffic.

Comment: Is it a fairly simple process to set up my laptop running Windows 10 as an ad hoc access point? Or would it be easier to use say a raspberry pi as an AP?

Comment: Depends on your experience with Raspberry Pi. I have not used it as an AP, and I do not know how to run Wireshark on it. For Windows 10, here is a link that will give you some idea what is involved.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/how-do-i-set-up-an-ad-hoc-wifi-network-in-windows/0caa92d8-e02f-4e7f-aa5c-0abf10ed2039